# How to inject service into gridApi event?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angularjs-resource

I have a ng-resource service in my controller (let's call it **Items**):

```
app.factory("Items", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/items/:id");
});
```

Want to make a POST request to save edits using my **Items** service:

```
$scope.items_grid.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi, Items) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.$apply();
            var field = colDef['name'];
            Items.get({'id':rowEntity._id.$oid}, function(item) {
                item[field] = newValue;
                item.$save;
            }); 
        });
    };
```

But on console I got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`.

How to properly inject my service on **afterCellEdit** event?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because the `onRegisterApi` function doesn't support dependency injection and `Items` is equal to `undefined` or something else (try to log it in console)...

You can retrieve dependencies using the `$injector` or declaring them as a function parameter, but, only where IoC is implemented...

If you cannot access to any of them, at least, you can do something like that:
`var Items = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('Items');`

---

please post your full controller script in order to have a more elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `Items` to your controller, rather than passing it as function parameter.

Dependency gets injected from the controller function, not from the function parameter. Basically you need to inject the `Items` service dependency in angular `controller` where `$scope.items_grid.onRegisterApi` belongs.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, Items){ //<--inject items dependency here

   //you controller code

   $scope.items_grid.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) { //<-- removed Items from here
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.$apply();
            var field = colDef['name'];
            Items.get({'id':rowEntity._id.$oid}, function(item) {
                item[field] = newValue;
                item.$save; //this line seems doubtful
            }); 
        });
    };

})
```

Comment: @Paul Serikov does it helped?